# Clean3.0 get directory contents

Tags: clean-language

I am using Cleanide for `Clean3.0` programming language.
What I am trying to do is to implement a function that receive name of a directory in my system, and return a list of all the files in that directory.

I don't know if the defintion of such function needs to be like `File -> [string]` or maybe something else, even that directory is a file maybe this is not the developers of `Clean` meant...

Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is not available in the StdEnv environment, but there are two libraries that can help with this:

- The [Directory](https://clean.cs.ru.nl/Directory) library contains a module [Directory](https://cloogle.org/src/#Directory/Directory) which has a function `getDirectoryContents :: !Path !*env -> (!(!DirError, [DirEntry]), !*env)  | FileSystem env`.
- The [Platform](https://gitlab.science.ru.nl/clean-and-itasks/clean-platform/) library contains a module [System.Directory](https://cloogle.org/src/#Platform/System/Directory) which has a function `readDirectory :: !FilePath !*w -> (!MaybeOSError [FilePath], !*w)`.

In both cases the first argument is a path to the directory and the second argument is the `*World`, which is the typical way of Clean to perform impure operations (see [chapter 9](https://cloogle.org/doc/#CleanRep.2.2_11.htm;jump=_Toc311798092) of [the language report](http://clean.cs.ru.nl/download/doc/CleanLangRep.2.2.pdf)).

#### Code examples

With Directory:

```
import Directory

Start w
# (dir,w) = getDirectoryContents (RelativePath []) w
= dir
```

With Platform:

```
import System.Directory

Start w
# (dir,w) = readDirectory "." w
= dir
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please consider the fact that I'm beginner, can you post a code example?

Comment: @ZENir I have updated the answer with examples for both modules.

Comment: Thanks. I still not sure how to get the contents of a specific directory. lets say `"C:\Users\User\myDir"` can you help me with that?

Comment: @ZENir You would use that as the first argument. So e.g. `"C:\\Users\\User\\myDir"` for Platform or `AbsolutePath "C" [PathDown "Users",PathDown "User",PathDown "myDir"]` for Directory.